# Symfony Doctrine SQLSTATE 42S02 Base Table or View not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, akeneo

I create a Table with Doctrine using this in a Symfony Bundle class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\TranslationMessagesProducerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_translation_config")
 *
 */
class AcmeTranslationMessagesProducerEntity{
    
    /**
     * id - for doctrine
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
    
    /**
     * enabled
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $enabled;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getEnabled(){
        return $this->enabled;
    }

}
```

and this table is existing after running
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
i can verify it is existing by querying
`php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "Select * From acme_translation_config`
or also run:
`php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "Select * From akeneo_pim.acme_translation_config`

Doctrine also recognizes it, verified by running:
`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info`
with result:

```
Found 58 mapped entities: .... 
Acme\Bundle\TranslationMessagesProducerBundle\Entity\AcmeTranslationMessagesProducerEntity
```

However if i try to get a object from this table like this:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $config = $em->getRepository(AcmeTranslationMessagesProducerEntity::class)->find(1);
```

i get the fail:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'akeneo_pim.acme_translation_config' doesn't exist
```

How could one resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to update the database schema. "php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Comment: Yes. Didnt work. But i figured out why this happens. It has to do with how Akeneo works along with Docker. I defined everything right but didnt execute the command in the right place.

Comment: For anyone encountering this problem too in a akeneo dev docker image: you cant run "php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force" from a simple console, you need to connect in your akeneo docker container with docker exec and run the command there. Then everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_translation_config")
 *
 */
```

By this :

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AcmeTranslationMessagesProducerEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_translation_config")
 *
 */
```

And check `AcmeTranslationMessagesProducerEntityRepository.php` exists

PS : You should follow the naming rules by not adding "Entity" to your class name : `AcmeTranslationMessagesProducer` is better than `AcmeTranslationMessagesProducerEntity`